# Facing issue while passing parameter to azure yaml pipeline using Azure Build API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

### I tried using parameters in pipeline per below ::

- name: var1
  displayName: var1
  type: string
  default: variable2
  values:

  - variable2
  - variable3
  - variable4

---

now when i am trying to hit by postman and passing parameter in body per below

post call to --> https://dev.azure.com/<org_name>/<prj_name>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0
body -->

{
"definition": {"id": 1234},
"var1":"variable1"
}

---

still when i get the parameter value in pipeline.. i get the default value and not the one i passed using api.

echo "Passed variable is ${{ parameters.var1 }}"
output --> Passed variable is variable2

Thanks
Sharad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue we have reported to the product team : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1000544/parameters-to-api-rest-build-queue-method.html

Currently as a workaround we can use below undocumented REST API (tracked by develop tool) to trigger the YAML pipeline by passing the parameters.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview.1

Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Request body:

{
 "stagesToSkip":[],
 "resources":{
   "repositories":{
     "self":{
       "refName":"refs/heads/master"
       }
    }
 },
 "templateParameters":{
   "image":"ubuntu-16.04",
   "var1":"variable1"
   },
  "variables":{}
}
```

Yaml file for your reference:

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - vs2017-win2016
  - ubuntu-latest
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - macOS-latest
  - macOS-10.14

- name: var1 
  displayName: var1 
  type: string 
  default: variable2 
  values:
  - variable1 
  - variable2
  - variable3
  - variable4


trigger: none


jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.var1 }}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Andy. it worked..!!!!! just want to make sure, is it good to use this API as this code would then go uptil prod.. any would it be release in near future somehow..

Comment: The API is tracked from the UI action, so it will always work unless the UI action does not work anymore. Not sure if this will be documented in further release. Actually current [queue build REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is designed for the classic pipelines (non-yaml). Whatever, yes it's good to use this API in your code.